# Is it "pythonic" to add attributes into class instance in runtime?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a set of class instances to operate on. But I need some additional status variables per instance. The instance is not aware of them.
Is it recommended to simply put such extra variable as attribute into an instance like this:
`instances[x].extra_status_attribute = x`,
or it is better to keep them separately?

Comment: IMO it would more Pythonic to use a dictionary in the class and check that to see if an attribute exists in it. i.e. `if attribute_name in self.attrs:`. This is very similar to a class instance's attributes, which are usually represented as entries in the instance's `__dict__`, but arguably more obvious about what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to prescribe what is "Pythonic" or not, since programming styles differ and what is Pythonic can be subject to change.

That said, one of the dogmas of Python is "Explicit is better than Implicit". I would say for the sake of anyone using my code that when declaring a class I would make it explicitly known what variables I intend to use, and then document them as such.

This is my opinion. Your Mileage May Vary.